# Reading Json arrays with Swift 5

Tags: arrays, json, swift, nsarray, swift5

I have a following json while after i make an api call

```
[{"breeds":
[{"weight":{"imperial":"7 - 14","metric":"3 - 6"},"id":"ebur","description":" Something ","child_friendly":4,}]
,"url":"https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/YOjBThApG.jpg","width":2838,"height":4518}]
```

As you can see, there are nested arrays and the output from this api call
I want to get `Id` and `url`. I process my dataTask output just like that

```
let jsonResponse = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
guard let jsonArray = jsonResponse as? [[String: Any]] else {
                          return
                    }
```

So i can access url with no problem  `print(jsonArray[0]["url"])` and i can also do `jsonArray[0]["breeds"]`. However, I cant do `jsonArray[0]["breeds"]["decription"]` or `jsonArray[0]["breeds"]["id"]`. because i get the following error `Value of type 'Any?' has no subscripts` I suspect that the problem is in `[[String: Any]]`. How would i change my jsonResponse conversion to an array to get the right output for the calls

Comment: Why are you not using `Codable`?

Comment: How would I use Codable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast any subscripted value

```
if let breeds = jsonArray.first?["breeds"] as? [[String:Any]],
   let description = breeds.first?["description"] as? String {
     print(description)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) and can use [Quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io) to generate your structs from json easily.

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Parameters
struct Parameters: Codable {
    let breeds: [Breed]?
    let url: String?
    let width, height: Int?
}

// MARK: - Breed
struct Breed: Codable {
    let weight: Weight?
    let id, breedDescription: String?
    let childFriendly: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case weight, id
        case breedDescription = "description"
        case childFriendly = "child_friendly"
    }
}

// MARK: - Weight
struct Weight: Codable {
    let imperial, metric: String?
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But when I do                        `do {
                        let breed = try JSONDecoder().decode([Breed].self, from: data!)
                        } catch { print(error) }` I get an error `keyNotFound` Do I have to precrocess the Json data before i feed it in?

Comment: No, you just need to compose your structures the same way as json.

Comment: your `data` is not `[Breed]` it is like `Parameters` in my post